# Is there a .NET standard equivalent of ValidationProblemDetails for clients to consume?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I am developing a mobile application that uses an ASP.NET Core API that responds using the standard error classes (ValidationProblemDetails and ProblemDetails). Is there a .NET standard class that I can deserialize these into for consumption in my mobile application? Thanks!

Comment: The ASP.Net Core libraries are already .NET Standard libraries. Just use the ASP.Net Core 2 libraries which adhere to .NET Standard 2.1 and can be used in .NET Framework and IIRC Xamarin.

Comment: I think that the library is linked as a `netcoreapp` which makes it off limits in a Xamarin project. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: ValidationProblemDetails is part of [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails) which is a [.NET Standard 2.0 library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) - look into the .nupkg file which is just a zip file (another hint is the dependencies section on the site which lists all the other AspNetCore libraries as .NET Standard).

Comment: @ckuri It worked! Thank you so much for your help. If you write an answer, I can upvote it.